# Handling network errors with axios and Twilio

Tags: javascript, network-programming, twilio, axios, twilio-api

I have an application that uses axios for it's ajax requests. When a user experiences a network issue (for example, their wifi goes out and they no longer have an internet connection while on my application), I want to make sure that only the first axios request is made, and if I detect there is a network issue, to not attempt any more requests, but instead to retry the same request until successful.

My application performs many requests, including a request every 2.5 seconds (in this example, `getData`). It also establishes a Twilio connection when the application initializes (it executes `twilio()` on initialization).

When a connection is lost, the following happens:

1. `getData` fails, resulting in a console message of `this is a network error.`
2. `TwilioDevice.offline` is executed. This results in two error messages: first a `this is a network error.` message (error message #2) when `TwilioDevice.offline` tries `fetchToken()`, and then a `received an error.` message (error message #3) after the `fetchToken()` fails.

Given #'s 1 and 2, how can I make sure that:

- If I experience a network error, I only receive one error message instead of 3 saying that "there was a network error"
- My app detects that there is a network error, then tries to re-establish a connection, then, if successful, resumes fetching data, Twilio tokens, etc.

Thanks! Code is below.

**example code:**

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('api/data');
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error);
  }
};

const fetchToken = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await axios.get('api/twilio-token');
    return data.token;
  } catch (error) {
    return handleError(error);
  }
};

const handleError = error => {
  if (!error.response) {
    console.log("this is a network error.");
  } else {
    console.log("received an error.");
  }
};
```

**twilio.js:**

```
import { Device as TwilioDevice } from 'twilio-client';

const registerEvents = () => {
  TwilioDevice.ready(() => {
    console.log('Twilio.Device is now ready for connections');
  });
  TwilioDevice.connect((conn) => {
    console.log(`Connecting call with id ${conn.parameters.CallSid}`);
    // code to start call
    conn.disconnect((connection) => {
      console.log(`Disconnecting call with id ${connection.parameters.CallSid}`);
      // code to end call
    });
  });
  TwilioDevice.error((error) => {
    console.log("Twilio Error:");
    console.log(error);
  });
  TwilioDevice.offline(async () => {
    try {
      const newTwilioToken = await fetchToken(); // error message #2
      return TwilioDevice.setup(newTwilioToken);
    } catch (error) {
      return handleError(error); // error message #3
    }
  });
};

export const twilio = async () => {
  try {
    registerEvents();
    const twilioToken = await fetchToken();
    TwilioDevice.setup(twilioToken);
  } catch (error) {
    return handleError(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: I see a lot of logging but not really doing anything with it. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend making your `fetchToken` and `getData` methods to throw errors rather than handling it themselves so that they can be handled by their outer functions.

Something like,

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('api/data');
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw (error);
  }
};

const fetchToken = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await axios.get('api/twilio-token');
    return data.token;
  } catch (error) {
    throw (error);
  }
};
```

So that when you call `twilio()` that function can handle the error like retrying  etc.